# Model in Maya looks strange, what went wrong?

Tags: 3d, models, maya

I am modeling a tank and I don't know what key I've pressed, but now the object in Maya is looking very weird.

[image: image of tank with some parts visible that shouldn't be and some strange artifacting]

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Looks some faces have inverted normals? I don't use Maya so I can't tell you how to fix that. Make regular backups... Have you tried "Undo"?

Comment: Yeah stupid of me, Undo doesn't work because I saved and restarted the program, because I thought it was just a bug...

Comment: Nothing helps, flipping normals, faces, just nothing :( god why I put so much work in this...

Comment: Does it only look this way in shaded mode? How about wireframe? Does that look normal?

Comment: Is it possible to link to a larger image?

Comment: Larger image: www.jamax.nl/problem3
Wireframe: www.jamax.nl/problem2

Wireframe looks normal. Still thanks for trying to help me out you guys :)

Comment: @Joris You made a boo boo. [Larger image](http://www.jamax.nl/problem3.png) / [Wireframe](http://www.jamax.nl/problem2.png)

Comment: Random wierd issues (or me just not catching something immediately) is why I turned on the incremental saves feature.  I've currently got it limited to the previous 5, but unless the model is huge, you could probably set it to infinity.  I think it also saves camera state, although if it doesn't, the fact that you would know you had a 'good' model should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was due to z-fighting in an inaccurate depth buffer. The reason the depth buffer got inaccurate was because your camera's near and far clipping planes had gotten too far apart. Basically, the depth buffer has a limited number of possible depth values that are spread out between the near and far clipping planes. Thus as the clipping planes get further apart, the depth values spread apart as well.

I believe the far clipping plane in Maya gets pushed out automatically as you zoom the camera, so going to an extreme zoom will cause this issue.

The reason pasting your model in a new file fixed the issue was because the camera's near and far clipping planes were reset.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue you want to go to

1. view>camera attribute editor. in the panel windows, and then in the attribute editor change the
2. near clip plane to 0.100 (or whatever works for your scene).
3. far clip plane to 10000.000 (or whatever works for your scene).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I fixed it. I just had to copy the object, open a new file and paste it in there. I still don't know what the cause of this problem was, but this is a solution.

Thanks everyone for helping, thanks a lot!

Comment: This likely means that your issue was what jhocking suggests.

Comment: jhocking would probably appreciate you choosing his answer as the correct one...

Comment: I answered earlier then he did, so I didn't have the chance...

Comment: Also you should learn to have a little patience, I'm not on gamedev all day, I have a busy life next to this.